# Find the characteristic polynomial of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to find the characteristic polynomial of: $$ A= \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \cdots & \alpha_{55} & \\ 
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \cdots & \alpha_{55} & \\ 
\vdots   & \vdots   & \ddots & \vdots      & \\ 
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \cdots & \alpha_{55} & 
\end{pmatrix} $$
$\forall i: 1\leq i\leq 55: a_i$ are scalars.

I didn't actually got the trick here, any advice?

Comment: Thank you for your hint and comment, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1-\lambda & \alpha_2 & \cdots & \alpha_{55} & \\ 
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2-\lambda & \cdots & \alpha_{55} & \\ 
 . & . & . & . & \\ 
 .& . & . & . & \\ 
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \cdots & \alpha_{55}-\lambda & 
\end{pmatrix} $$

Substract the first row from every other row

$$ =\det\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1-\lambda & \alpha_2 & \cdots & \alpha_{55} & \\ 
\lambda & -\lambda & \cdots & 0 & \\ 
 . & . & . & . & \\ 
 .& . & . & . & \\ 
\lambda & 0 & \cdots & -\lambda & 
\end{pmatrix} $$

Compute the transpose

$$ =\det\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1-\lambda & \lambda & \cdots & \lambda & \\ 
\alpha_2 & -\lambda & \cdots & 0 & \\ 
 . & . & . & . & \\ 
 .& . & . & . & \\ 
\alpha_{55} & 0 & \cdots & -\lambda & 
\end{pmatrix} $$

Add every row to the first one

$$ =\det\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1+\cdots +\alpha_{55}-\lambda & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \\ 
\alpha_2 & -\lambda & \cdots & 0 & \\ 
 . & . & . & . & \\ 
 .& . & . & . & \\ 
\alpha_{55} & 0 & \cdots & -\lambda & 
\end{pmatrix} $$

Therefore you get $\lambda^{54}(\alpha -\lambda)$ where $\alpha=\alpha_1+\cdots +\alpha_{55}$.

Comment: This one I like.

Comment: I also like this answer, it covers the case $\alpha=0$. Thank you all for your time and effort! I really appreciate it you helped me a lot! thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

The case $\alpha_i=0\ \forall i$ is trivial so let's treat the general case

The rank of the matrix $A$ is $1$ so by the rank nullity theorem $\dim \ker A=54$ and then $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $54$ and the last eigenvalue is $\displaystyle \mathrm{tr}(A)=\sum_{k=1}^{55}\alpha_i=\lambda$ and then
$$\chi_A(x)=x^{54}(x-\lambda)$$

Comment: I'm confused about something. How do you conclude that $\lambda \neq 0$? Or if you allow it to be $0$, how do you make sure you're not already counting it in the rank nullity theorem?

Comment: $\lambda$ my be $0$ for example take $\alpha_1=1$ and $\alpha_2=-1$ and the other $\alpha_i=0$.

Comment: Yes and my second question?

Comment: Thank you both for your answers!
@GitGud 
But what happens if all α 1 +...+α 55  =0 ?

Comment: I don't well understand this question but the only matrix with $\dim\ker A=55$ is the zero matrix.

Comment: @ChristinBrown Notice that $\alpha _i \ge 0$.

Comment: @GitGud I think it's a typo and he means $1\leq i\leq 55$

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I'm thinking of a way to reask the question.

Comment: I'm truly sorry!! I meant that for $\forall i: 1\leq i\leq 55: a_i$ are scalars! (there is no assumption on where are they taken from).
I've edited the question.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Let $\alpha$ be the trace of the matrix. We know that $A$ is similar to an upper triangular matrix $T$ whose diagonal is $\text{diag}_T(\lambda, 0, \ldots ,0)$. Why is it that $\alpha = \lambda$? Equivalently, why is it the case $\alpha$ isn't one of the other $0$'s in the diagonal?

Comment: @GitGud We proved that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity at least $54$ and the trace $\alpha$ is invariant by similarity so $\alpha=0+\cdots+0+\lambda=\lambda$.

Comment: @GitGud Answering your last comment: yes, if you want to give full details. But it is really as simple as Sami wrote it. IF $A=0$, trivial. If $A\neq 0$, $0$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $54$. Triangularize if you want: the remaining diagonal value is the trace, it could be $0$, no problem.